# Query/force only certain geometry types returned from ST_Intersection?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, intersection, geometry-conversion

I have `ST_MultiLineString` geometry records in `table_a` that I'm intersecting with `ST_MultiPolygon` geometry records in `table_b`.

Nearly all of the returned GeoJSON is of type `LineString` but a few are type `Point` (cases where the intersection results in an isolated point). The returned GeoJSON is styled as a line resulting in the point type geometry displaying default leaflet point markers.

I tried `ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_MakeLine(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)))` but it is connecting *all* of the lines/points in a way that's clearly incorrect.

Is there a way to only return intersection geometry of a specific type or otherwise correctly convert/force the intersection geometry to `LineString`?

Comment: There's a [bucket of ST_* functions available](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ch07.html), including the only non-ST function, `GeometryType`

Comment: ST_CollectionExtract()

Comment: There is also a ST_ prefixed version http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_GeometryType.html. Just filter with `WHERE GeometryType='WhatYouWant'`.

Comment: @ziggy `ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_CollectionExtract(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom),2))` did the trick, if you'd like to add as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function https://postgis.net/docs/ST_CollectionExtract.html will allow you to specify which geometry to select from a geometry collection. ST_Intersection sometimes outputs to a geometry collection (my assumption for this would be because of lat lng point rounding errors that make up the points, lines or polygons being intersected)

```
ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_CollectionExtract(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom),2))
```